# How to publish a BAM event with an attribute of type long via rest-api?

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

According to logs I've managed to create an event stream definition using rest-api.

```
[2012-08-22 08:48:57,287]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.streamdefn.cassandra.datastore.CassandraConnector} -  Saving Stream Definition : StreamDefinition{streamId='labit.stream-0.0.3-67a2ed14-ece6-4d98-a904-0dde7892c3a9', name='labit.stream', version='0.0.3', nickName='null', description='LONG and BigINT Test stream', tags=null, metaData=[Attribute{name='myTimeStamp', type=LONG}, Attribute{name='source', type=STRING}], correlationData=null, payloadData=[Attribute{name='fibonacciNumber', type=INT}]}
```

But when I try to publish an event..

```
[
    {
    "payloadData" : [1] ,
    "metaData" : [1340279541606, "labittest"]
    }
]
```

..to it using rest-api, an exception is raised.

```
[2012-08-22 08:51:48,797] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.streamdefn.cassandra.subscriber.BAMEventSubscriber} -  Error processing event. 
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.streamdefn.cassandra.inserter.LongInserter.addDataToBatchInsertion(LongInserter.java:31)
at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.streamdefn.cassandra.datastore.CassandraConnector.prepareDataForInsertion(CassandraConnector.java:690)
at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.streamdefn.cassandra.datastore.CassandraConnector.insertEventList(CassandraConnector.java:489)
at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.streamdefn.cassandra.subscriber.BAMEventSubscriber.receive(BAMEventSubscriber.java:41)
at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker.run(QueueWorker.java:64)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

On the other hand I'm able to publish an event to the same stream from Java code.

```
dataPublisher.publish(labitStream, new Object[] { 1340279541606L, "labittest" }, null, new Object[] { 1 });
```

The version of WSO2 BAM2 I'm using is the one extracted from wso2bam-2.0.0-BETA.zip .

So the question is: how can I publish events with attributes of long type using rest-api?

Comment: I tested this out with a long and it just worked. Can you include your stream definition as well to so that the issue can be exactly reproduced?

Comment: The used stream definition is: `{
    "name":"labit.stream",
    "version": "0.0.3",
    "description": "Long and BigInt Test stream",
    "metaData":[
        {
            "name":"myTimeStamp",
            "type":"long"
        }
        ,
        {
            "name":"source",
            "type":"string"
        }
    ],
    "payloadData":[
        {
            "name":"fibonacciNumber",
            "type":"int"
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: I managed to reproduce the problem. A jira has been created at https://wso2.org/jira/browse/BAM-793. This will be fixed for the release.

Comment: This has been fixed with revision 139770 in the release branch. I will point to a link when a binary is available with this fix.

Answer (score 0):

A beta2 with this issue fixed is hosted at the [product download page](http://wso2.com/products/business-activity-monitor)